# Does call View.setEnabled() involve View.setClickable()?

Tags: android

I need to disallow user interraction with a couple of views in activity's layout for some period(depending on specified event occure). Do i have to call both `setEnabled()` and `setClickable()` methods or maybe `setEnabled()` implicitly involves `setClickable`?

Comment: setEnabled() is enough